# Stored procedure NULL values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, null

I have a stored procedure that selects data out of a view and inserts it into a `tempTable` based on criteria. What I'm trying to do is make sure that if there are NULL values for added date, they get excluded.

```
Insert into tempIntake(Pop, PlanID, PopFull, ApptDate, 1stAppt, Followup, Rn, UserID)
select Pop, PlanID, PopFull, InterviewDate, 1stAppt, Followup, rn, @UserID 
from 
   (Select *, row_number() over (partition by PlanID order BY AddedDate ASC) as rn 
     from VInfo) t
where rn = 1 
and interviewdate >= @fromDate 
and interviewDate <= @toDate
```

How would I do that?

I'm basically trying to filter by the earlier ADDEDDATE but exclude the NULL dates that might appear.

I have this SP and I also have another stored Procedure that does ADDEDDATE DESC. But I don't know if this likes the fact that I only have one date. For teh ASC partition, it pulls a null value, and for DESC it pulls an actual date (there is only one date). I want to be able to use that date in both stored Procedures (unless there are multiple dates - that's when I'd like it do grab the earliest date and latest date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, a simple where clause in the derived table should do the trick:

```
Insert into tempIntake(Pop, PlanID, PopFull, ApptDate, 1stAppt, Followup, Rn, UserID)
select Pop,PlanID, PopFull,InterviewDate,1stAppt,Followup, rn, @UserID 
from (
    Select *,row_number() over (partition by PlanID order BY AddedDate ASC) as rn 
    from VInfo
    where AddedDate is not null 
) t
where rn = 1 
and interviewdate >=@fromDate 
and interviewDate <=@toDate
```

**Update**

Following our conversation in the comments i think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
Insert into tempIntake(Pop, PlanID, PopFull, ApptDate, 1stAppt, Followup, Rn, UserID)
select Pop,PlanID, PopFull,InterviewDate,1stAppt,Followup, rn, @UserID 
from (
    Select *,row_number() over (partition by PlanID order BY AddedDate ASC) as rn 
    from VInfo
    where AddedDate is not null 
) t
where rn = 1 
and interviewdate >=@fromDate 
and interviewDate <=@toDate

union 

select Pop,PlanID, PopFull,InterviewDate,'2016-01-01',Followup, rn, @UserID 
from (
    Select *,row_number() over (partition by PlanID order BY AddedDate ASC) as rn 
    from VInfo t1
    where AddedDate is null 
    and not exists 
    (
        select 1
        from VInfo t
        where AddedDate is not null 
        and interviewdate >=@fromDate 
        and interviewDate <=@toDate
    )
) t
where rn = 1 
and interviewdate >=@fromDate 
and interviewDate <=@toDate
```

Comment: Is what you edited with the partition enough for me to pull data by the earliest date, where date is not null???

Comment: the `row_number()` is calculated with the `select` clause, so it only counts the rows after they have been filtered by the `where` clause.

Comment: For PlanID - at time I have multiple Dates in some cases, but I also sometimes only have one date, and other values are NULL. Why is it when I only have one date and run the SP that i included in question is that I pull the NULL value when i do Partition by PlanID order by AddedDate ASC, however, when I i do... Partition by PlanID order by AddedDate Desc I get the date. I want to be able to use the date in both cases. For some reason, when I include where addeddate is not null - i don't get all my data(i guess some PlanID's don't have added date)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in this comment.

Comment: is it possible for me to specify that IF addedDate is null then make it 1/1/2016 - or in this case i'd like to say that if ADDEDdate is null then 1/1/2016 and 1stAppt = NULL